# Execution time between JS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

In index.php I create the following variables with JS inside the HTML head tag:

```
var phpMicrotime = <?php echo round(microtime(1) * 1000); ?>;
var jsDateMicrotime = (new Date()).getTime();
```

Then with every ajax request I include:

```
(new Date()).getTime() - jsDateMicrotime + phpMicrotime
```

In ajax.php I then use this value to get the time it took for the request:

```
round(microtime(1) * 1000) - $_POST["requestTimeSent"]
```

So here's the problem;

If it takes a few seconds to load index.php then jsDateMicrotime and phpMicrotime will be out of sync, so I need to subtract an offset which I figured I could do with window.performance.timing for JS. However, I can't figure out which value to use, or if it's even possible to get the loading time between the php and js execution using that approach.

Comment: why are you stringifying the getTime value only to parse it back to a number?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @knittl The inconsistency of `alert(jsDateMicrotime - phpMicrotime);`.

Comment: @Mandera: yes, but why do you need that value at all? What is the problem you have when sending a not-so-accurate timestamp in your ajax-call?

Comment: @knittl If `round(microtime(1) * 1000) - $_POST["requestTimeSent"]` is greater than a certain value then ajax.php will exit(). So atm I have it set to 8 seconds, but if it took 5 seconds between the PHP and JS execution then it will exit if the request took more than only 3 seconds.

Comment: I was unaware of xmlhttp.timeout, so I'll just use that instead of my custom functions.